# R Benchmarking package: Error in -XREF[, h] : invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: python, r, benchmarking, economics

I need to run a Data Envelopment Analysis model based on a data frame that I built, in csv format. After a bit of research into what software and package would be easier, I found R's Benchmarking package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Benchmarking/index.html.

However, when I try to run the code:

```
#loading the dataframe

IES<-read.csv("_INPUTS & OUTPUTS.csv", sep=";")

#specifying input and output matrix

(x <- with(IES, cbind(STUDENTS, FACULTY, AGE, PHD, MA, PRES, FTE, FTNE, PART, HOUR, TEC, TEC_SUP, TEC_SPEC, TEC_MA, TEC_PHD, PORTAL_CAPES, VIRT_JOURNAL, VIRT_BOOK, VL_DESPESA_PESSOAL_DOCENTE, VL_DESPESA_PESSOAL_TECNICO, VL_DESPESA_PESSOAL_ENCARGO, VL_DESPESA_CUSTEIO, VL_DESPESA_INVESTIMENTO, VL_DESPESA_PESQUISA, VL_DESPESA_OUTRA)))
(y <- matrix(IES$ST_COMPLETING))

#running the model

dea(x,y, RTS="vrs", ORIENTATION="out")
```

I get the following error:

> Error in -XREF[, h] : invalid argument to unary operator

I have checked the dataframe and there are no problems there. Also tried the input "in" orientation, but get the same error.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't know anything about this package, but I don't think having STUDENTS as both an input and an output is correct.

Comment: In fact, that is wrong and I had not seen it. The output variable should be ST_COMPLETING, representing students that have graduated in a specific year. Anyway, fixed that but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Problem was that the .csv file used had ',' as the decimal separator. So all I had to do was specify it when reading it.